# What are the drawbacks in my form design logic?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```js
$('.login_links_register').click(

function () {
    $("body").addClass("removeScroll");
    $(".login_form_container").show();
    $("#registerForm").show();
    $(".login_form_container").css('top', '0px');
    /*$('.overlay').addClass('visible');*/
});


$(document).on('click', ".close_button",

function (event) {
    var negativeHeight = -1 * ($('.login_form_container').offset().top + $(this).parents('.login_form_container').height());
    $(".login_form_container").css('top', negativeHeight);
    //$(".login_form_container").slideUp();
    /*$('.overlay').removeClass('visible');*/
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.overlay').addClass('displayNone');
        $(".login_links").removeClass("popup_opened");
        $("#loginForm").hide();
        $("#registerForm").hide();
        $("body").removeClass("removeScroll");
    }, 500); /*Execute a set of statements after a statement completion. To make it faster reduce the milliseconds*/
});
```

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.header2 {
    background-color:#E1E3E5;
    /*have to change */
    /*padding: 15px 0;*/
}
.right {
    float: right;
    clear:both;
    /*To avoid problems caused by float - but check it may cause some problems check for it*/
}
/*Instead overflow:auto(or) hidden*/
 .clearboth::after {
    clear: both;
    content:"";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}
.emailField, .passwordField {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*to remove unnecessary margin caused by ul element */
 .login_links_list {
    /*margin:10px 0;*/
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
.login_links.right {
    margin-right: 70px;
    /*Same as Login container*/
}
/*login_link ul li element*/
 .login_links_list_ele, .login_links_list_label
/*can apply al these properties to anchor tag instead li */
 {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.login_links_list_label {
    padding: 15px;
}
.login_links_register, .login_links_login {
    /*border-right:1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
.login_form_container.right {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin-right: 70px;
    /* For better alignment. Instead kissing the edge of the screen*/
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    position: relative;
    top: -173px;
    /* For Styling. instead displayNone*/
    z-index: 2;
}
/*positioning close button*/
 .close_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    width: 17px;
}
.loginDiv.right {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headers header2 clearboth" id="header2">
      <nav class="login_links right">
   <ul class="login_links_list right">
      <li class="login_links_list_label">Are you a member?</li>
      <li id="login_links_register" class="login_links_list_ele login_links_register">Register</li>
      <li id="login_links_login" class="login_links_list_ele login_links_login">login</li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="login_form_container right displayNone">
  <form class="right registerForm" id="registerForm" method="POST" action="lib/registration_validate.php">
   <img class="close_button close_popup close_register_form" src="image/close_icon.png"></img>
   
   <div class="register_input">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="register_links emailID" type="text" placeholder="Email ID" name="email"/>
   </div>
   
   <div class="register_input">
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="register_links password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
   </div>
   
   <div class="register_input">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="register_links conf_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword"/>
   </div>
   
   <div class="register_submission">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" class="register_button"></input>
    <div class="custom_checkbox_div">
     <input id="custom_checkbox" class="custom_checkbox_input" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me" name="remMeCheckbox"/>
     <label for="custom_checkbox" class="custom_checkbox_label"></label>
     <label class="custom_checkbox_string" for="custom_checkbox">Remember Me</label>
    </div>              
   </div>
```

This is in my `HTML` page. I have `negative top` to show and hide forms for better views.

Please clear me the following doubts

1) I have to send the data to server when user submits form. I do client-side and server-side validation. If client-side validation fails, I 'll show the errors in the form itself. If there is any `server-side error`, how do i show this in the form?

My ideas:
   I have to insert some `php error tags` in the html page and change my `filetype to php from html` so that if there is any server side error `i ll insert the error in those tags`.

```
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
```

Something like the above.

(or)

Take the user to another php page where user re-enter the details. and handles all the error in the same page.

2) What are the problems with this type of negative top form design?

Please let me know the problems and suitable solutions so that i get clean design. I don't want the code only the idea.

Comment: One thing i can tell is about listening for `click` event on `document`. Though you are delegating but still every click on the page will be captured.

Comment: you can use ajax to perform the submit and pluck the feedback into the live form.

Comment: @dandavis you mean, i can use ajax to send data to the server. In the failure callback, i can show the errors in the same page itself

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I don't understand the term captured. Yes i am delegating the event for close button.

Comment: yes. depending on what the server returns that can be simple or complicated to implement. if your server returns a nice JSON error message, it's easy to steer the message to the right form input using jQuery. if it gives back an html page, then you need to "scrape" the messages from the result html and match them up with the live html, which is more involved. still, the over-all effect is very nice for users. look into $.serialize

Comment: @GopsAB What i meant was, whenever you click on the page, the event will be triggered but your callback won't be called because jQuery is handling it and checking if event target is matching delegate.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. I am new to php and ajax. I haven't used much. less knowledge only. To clear myself more, I can return `JSON` object from the server. Right?

Comment: yes, use php's `json_encode($myPHPObject)` to feed js an object from php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it but I am gonna stay low here by giving more of a hint to what you can do.

**Using AJAX to submit form?**

- If the validation fails in PHP...
- Create an associative array containing all the error messages and a key like `submitError` set to `TRUE`.
- `json_encode` the array and `die` or `return` it.
- In your JavaScript AJAX success callback, check for the existence of `submitError` key in the response.
- If `true`, parse and display all messages from the JSON response you received. Done!

**NOT using AJAX?**

- You can utilize `$_SESSION` to store the errors and related messages & set a flag for error.
- When the page loads/submits, check if `$_SESSION` contains that flag.
- If it does, pull the messages from session and display to the user.
- Once displayed, clear those things from `$_SESSION`

These things can be done for small applications. If you are using some kind of framework like CodeIgniter or Laravel, you may want to check their **session flash** methods.

**About Negative Top Form Design**

I don't see much of a problem there unless it's covering up something vital beneath it when opened. Specially on mobile version( if you plan to do that).

Comment: Thanks Warlock. It's for desktop version not for mobile version. Let me try all the methods.